# AOT: Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property '$' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, angular2-aot

I am trying to publish an Angular4 front-end project in AOT production build. After long hours of getting angular cli to successfully build in aot mode I was able to finally publish the front-end which was previously published with "build prod --aot false" and see the difference between AOT and JIT. Unfortunately I was getting below error when the webapp starts in the browser.

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property '$' of undefined
```

The error seemed related to jQuery (because of $) which I have in app.module.ts.

```
'import * as $ from 'jquery';'
```

But I realized that it wasn't jQuery related at all coz I was still getting the same error even if I completely removed jQuery references and usage in my app.

Note: I am only getting this error if the front-end was built with "prod --aot true" but not when the app is built with "prod --aot false"

Update: I also realized that I have SignalR service in the project which has below definition using the $ symbol.

```
export class SignalrWindow extends Window {
    $: any;
}
```

Not sure what's going on. Any help would be awesome!

Comment: And the code looks like... ?

Comment: did you install jquery and type for jquery

Comment: @sachilaranawaka : yes i've done npm install jquery --save and npm install @types/jquery --save

Comment: @Dekel , not sure which code to show because I'm not sure which one is breaking :) I have a big app.module.ts. import * as $ from jquery is the only line I could think of in app.module.ts, but the error doesn't tell much

Comment: Somewhere in your code you have `SOMETHING.$` and that `SOMETHING` is `undefined`...

Comment: @Dekel, Yes I have SignalR where I have window.$... Updated question with SignalR $ block

Comment: @Dekel, Thanks for pointing that out mate! My SignalR ts was the culprit!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new definition file (Ex: definitions.d.ts) and add the following code:

```
interface SignalrWindow extends Window {
    $: any;
}

declare var window: SignalrWindow ;
```

Comment: Yes, this worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

One way use the jquery instead of installing dependency is to add the jquery script to your `index.html` file and create a `define` variable.

**index.html**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
```

**app.module.ts**

```
declare var $: any;
```

The downside of this is, the IntelliSense will not work with the **define** variables.

Comment: I get "Cannot find name $" on ng build when I do what you suggested